# How to queue a shell command if [conditon] is not fulfilled?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, cron, queue

I am uploading data to a MySQL database from a shell script (from cron) every 5 minutes.
But if my connection is down, it does not insert it in to my database.

I would like the script to try to insert again and again (for example every 30 minutes) until it is successful.

And if my connection is down more than 5 minutes, I would like to these requests to stand in a queue and proceed when I have connection again.

How can I do that?
Example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cputemp=$(somecommands...)
/usr/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1  -u admin -pwpassword -e "USE logs; INSERT INTO cpu (cputemp) VALUES ('$cputemp');"
```

Comment: split the script into two parts. one that writes your values to a file, and then another that does the DB upload. That way if the db is down, you just keep growing your file. If the db upload succeeds, you delete the file and start over.

Comment: that should work, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it by writing in that logic into your code. Should be fairly easy detect it couldn't detect, have it sleep, then try again.